# inbuilt function matrix multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to find an inbuilt function to multiply two matrices in C++ on Google but all I can find are programs. Is there no simple way to get around this problem without writing a long code?

Comment: You should probably use Eigen, Intel's MKL, Lapack, or some other C++ basic linear algebra package. These all have optimized matrix multiplication implemented for you and some of them even allow for "C++-esque" syntax like `auto C = A*B`. No code needs to be written by you at all.

Comment: I've heard that Armadillo is good as well.

Comment: I highly recommend Eigen. Good docs and the entire thing is in header files. Very simple and reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have inbuilt functions for matrix manipulation, you need to use 3rd party library